# Display a text message on Desktop (OS X)

Tags: macos

I would like to display a message, for example, the OS Version, the installed tool versions etc of my OS X on the desktop background.

I understand that the lockscreen text can be edited, I am not talking about that. That is not what I am interested in.

I know there is a way because I have seen my colleagues at my previous job do this.

Comment: Did you ask your colleagues how they did it?

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @scott Hunter: Unfortunately I am not in touch with them anymore.

Comment: @paul: thanks, will give that a try.